# How can I extract a portion of a camera?

Tags: android, camera, imageview, android-framelayout

I'm using Camera in Android like this tutorial in my "Insert frame for photo" app
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html
I have a ImageView in FrameLayout to insert a image frame, with inside part is transparent.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/camera_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/demo" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I extract the frame image where the inside part is from the camera?

Answer (score 0):

```
        private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
        private static final int CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 200;

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                             data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    // User cancelled the image capture
                } else {
                    // Image capture failed, advise user
                }
            }

            if (requestCode == CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // Video captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved to:\n" +
                             data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    // User cancelled the video capture
                } else {
                    // Video capture failed, advise user
                }
            }
        }
```